# How would the momentum of photons affect the stability of a Dyson sphere?

Tags: gravity, photons

So a body surrounded by a shell experiences zero gravitational force, but how would the momentum of the photons affect a shell around a star? It seems like more force would be exerted on a near surface because it absorbs a higher density of photons per unit of area. Would that make a hypothetical Dyson sphere non-gravitationally stable around a sun?

Comment: A civilization that could build a Dyson sphere, can probably estimate the slight differences on the surface of its star, and design it in a way that make up the effect that you mentioned. Plus, having adjustment thrusters on every few thousand kilometers on the surface of the sphere, should be enough for having a stable Dyson sphere.